# How to implement a FlatDream Bootstrap theme in a Rails4 App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on my first ever Rails 4 app and have to integrate [FlatDream theme](http://condorthemes.com/flatdream/) in it. So far I could not find some easy to use and decent tutorial to stylized a Rails app based on a themeForest theme. Can you guide some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps.

1. Install gem "bootstrap-sass" if you don't already have it. You can install it by adding the following line to your gem file.

   gem "bootstrap-sass"
   bundle install
2. Next create a file named custom.css.scss (app/assets/stylesheets) and add the following two line to it

   @import "bootstrap";
   @import "bootstrap-responsive";
3. Next add the following to app/assets/javascript/application.js

   //= require bootstrap
4. Now you need to convert your your css files of your theme to scss. There are converters which can help you with this. Google is your best friend here. Put the scss files image files etc at right places. If the theme uses some custom javascript you need to add it to your project in standard manner.
5. You are good to go.

Comment: Is it necessary to convert css to scss? Will it not be good to put relevant asset files in certain folders?

Comment: You don't need to concert scss to css. CSS is a subset of SCSS so if you copy-paste or rename your css files with scss extension (xyz.css.scss) then it should work.